# Break-continue without auxiliary boolean variable?

Tags: java, label, break, goto, continue

In Java, I have such code:

```
boolean contains;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    // get the current matrix value
    t = A[i][j];

    // check if it has been already considered
    contains = false;
    for (int z = 0; z < l; z++) {
        if (arrays[z].contains(t)) {
            contains = true; break;
        }
    }
    if (contains) continue;
    ...
}
```

Is it possible to use label then jump out of the inner loop and do continue without a boolean variable `contains`?

**I need to do break-continue and not break from all loops.**

Comment: I would simply refactor the code and put the inner loop inside its own method. break and continue are like gotos. You'd better not use them.

Comment: A label on the outer loop and `continue outer;` does not work?

Comment: @Thilo do you mean like my answer ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
outerLoop:
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    // get the current matrix value
    t = A[[i]][j];
    // check if it has been already considered
    for (int z = 0; z < l; z++) {
        if (arrays[z].contains(t)) {
            continue outerLoop;
        }
    }
}
```

[Oracle's documentation on labelled branching](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html)

Comment: Yep-yep-yep!!! It's working now.. This solution is important because: 1) it is lovely; 2) it is less code; 3) it is faster because you do not use extra variable!!!

Answer (score 3):

Using labes leads to spaghetti code making your code less readable.

You could extract the inner for-loop in its own method returning a boolean:

```
private boolean contains(/* params */) {
    for (int z = 0; z < l; z++) {
        if (arrays[z].contains(t)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

and use it in the outer for-loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    // get the current matrix value
    t = A[[i]][j];

    // check if it has been already considered
    if (contains(/*params*/)) 
        continue;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, I thought about that, but it would be really nice to have break-continue construction because I do not like small methods.

Comment: Ouch! Then maybe you want to consider using "BASIC" and "GOTO"s ;) I consider this approach with a small method the cleanest.